# Google webmaster shows 'This site is undergoing a move' months after submission

Tags: google-search-console

I moved my website to a new domain and did all the necessary steps in Google Webmaster.

Now, months later, I'm trying to set the preferred domain to non-www and cannot because it says 'This site is undergoing a move'.

Could it still be in process? Should I 'Withdraw' and submit again or somehow contact Google?

Comment: Is this issue still unresolved? Could you give a timescale for the google change of address in Webmaster Tools approximately?